# Duplicate use of Wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins

I am stuck in a website and searching for someone to help me.

I am using "[Awesome Filterable Portfolio](http://wordpress.org/plugins/awesome-filterable-portfolio/)" plugin. I have to use it for different pages like Logo Design, Website, Print Graphics etc and other each page there will be some categories.

So How I can use the plugin more than once? I have tried to change the name and everything, but when I install it shows one single menu in Dashboard with two plugins menu.

Please help me: How i can use a plugin more than one time?.

Comment: Please link to the plugin so other don't have to search for it. Have you tried asking plugin's developer?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very generic answer but you can't just rename the plugin, you are also going to have to alter the [`add_menu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) and [`add_submenu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) registration code [starting around line 48](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/awesome-filterable-portfolio/trunk/afp.php#L48) and going to about line 81. You need to change at least the `$menu_slug` and `$parent_slug`, but probably want to change `$page_title` and `$menu_title` as well.

And you probably need to alter the `afp_get_new_portfolio_item_page` function so that one plugin does not clobber the options of another one.